# Redirection to html in dynamic web project in Java

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I have created a dynamic web project in Java. When I run the project with Tomcat server, it always hits index.html. I want to hit index.html in home folder, and then I write redirection to it on this way:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=../home/">
```

and a lot of other combination, but it always returns 404 not found. Does anyone have ideas how I could start page /home/index.html?
web.xml always hits the page in WebContent Folder

Here is how it looks.

[image]

Comment: Why do you put static content inside src folder?

Comment: I thought that static content also can be in src folder. @mauretto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your src folder does not contain sources but just static resources. You should avoid putting your css/html/images/js in this folder. Put all these in WebContent/css, WebContent/home, WebContent/images and WebContent/js and everything should work the right way.

Comment: I already use this solution, but i am interested why redirection doesn't work.

Comment: Things in src folder are not supposed to go to your application root directory but to WEB-INF/classes which is unreachable from a browser. That's why you HAVE to put your static resources in the WebContent directory like my answer mention and NOT in src.

Answer (score 1):

Write below code in your web.xml under  tag.

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/home/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I have tried that already, but web.xml again hits index.html in WebContent folder. @Rahul Sahu